# Changing this Python program to have function def()

Tags: python, function

The following Python program flips a coin several times, then reports the longest series of heads and tails. I am trying to convert this program into a program that uses functions so it uses basically less code. I am very new to programming and my teacher requested this of us, but I have no idea how to do it. I know I'm supposed to have the function accept 2 parameters: a string or list, and a character to search for. The function should return, as the value of the function, an integer which is the longest sequence of that character in that string. The function shouldn't accept input or output from the user.

```
import random

print("This program flips a coin several times, \nthen reports the longest 
series of heads and tails")

cointoss = int(input("Number of times to flip the coin: "))

varlist = [] 
i = 0
varstring = ' '

 while i < cointoss:
    r = random.choice('HT')

    varlist.append(r)
    varstring = varstring + r
    i += 1

print(varstring)

print(varlist)

print("There's this many heads: ",varstring.count("H"))
print("There's this many tails: ",varstring.count("T"))
print("Processing input...")

i = 0
longest_h = 0
longest_t = 0
inarow = 0
prevIn = 0

while i < cointoss:
    print(varlist[i])
    if varlist[i] == 'H':
        prevIn += 1
        if prevIn > longest_h:
            longest_h = prevIn
        print("",longest_h,"")

        inarow = 0

    if varlist[i] == 'T':
        inarow += 1
        if inarow > longest_t:
            longest_t = inarow
        print("",longest_t,"")

        prevIn = 0

    i += 1
print ("The longest series of heads is: ",longest_h)

print ("The longest series of tails is: ",longest_t)
```

If this is asking too much, any explanatory help would be really nice instead. All I've got so far is:

```
def flip (a, b):
    flipValue = random.randint
```

but it's barely anything.

Comment: `random.randint` will not call the function, you need parenthesis for that. You need to call it with `random.randint(lower_bound, upper_bound)`

Comment: If you have code like `a=b+1; c=b/2; d=a+b; result=d/4` and the variables `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d` are not used anywhere else in your code, that's a good candidate for a function. `def calculation(x): a=x+1; c=x/2; d=x+b; return d/4` forms the function and you'd call it like `result = calculation(b)`

Comment: Declaring `def flip(a,b): return random.randint(a,b)` doesn't really buy you anything, it's just a clumsy way to define `flip` as an alias for `random.randint`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import random
def Main():
    numOfFlips=getFlips()
    outcome=flipping(numOfFlips)
    print(outcome)
def getFlips():
    Flips=int(input("Enter number if flips:\n"))
    return Flips
def flipping(numOfFlips):
    longHeads=[]
    longTails=[]
    Tails=0
    Heads=0
    for flips in range(0,numOfFlips):
        flipValue=random.randint(1,2)
        print(flipValue)
        if flipValue==1:
            Tails+=1
            longHeads.append(Heads) #recording value of Heads before resetting it
            Heads=0
        else:
            Heads+=1
            longTails.append(Tails)
            Tails=0
    longestHeads=max(longHeads) #chooses the greatest length from both lists
    longestTails=max(longTails)
    return "Longest heads:\t"+str(longestHeads)+"\nLongest tails:\t"+str(longestTails)  
Main()
```

I did not quite understand how your code worked, so I made the code in functions that works just as well, there will probably be ways of improving my code alone but I have moved the code over to functions

Comment: I have a questions about this. How would I also make this program display the random list of heads and tails? Like in the program I originally posted, you'll notice how it displays a random list of heads and tails at the beginning, like 'HTTHTHHHTTT'

Comment: You could add a string containing "HT" and have an if statement: if the number is 1 the print the first half of the string, 2 then the other half of the string

Answer (score 0):

First, you need a function that flips a coin `x` times. This would be one possible implementation, favoring `random.choice` over `random.randint`:

```
def flip(x):
  result = []
  for _ in range(x):
    result.append(random.choice(("h", "t")))
  return result
```

Of course, you could also pass from what exactly we are supposed to take a choice as a parameter.

Next, you need a function that finds the longest sequence of some value in some list:

```
def longest_series(some_value, some_list):
  current, longest = 0, 0
  for r in some_list:
    if r == some_value:
      current += 1
      longest = max(current, longest)
    else:
      current = 0
  return longest
```

And now you can call these in the right order:

```
# initialize the random number generator, so we get the same result
random.seed(5)

# toss a coin a hundred times
series = flip(100)

# count heads/tails
headflips = longest_series('h', series)
tailflips = longest_series('t', series)

# print the results
print("The longest series of heads is: " + str(headflips))
print("The longest series of tails is: " + str(tailflips))
```

Output:

```
>> The longest series of heads is: 8
>> The longest series of heads is: 5
```

edit: removed the `flip` implementation with `yield`, it made the code weird.

Answer (score 0):

#### Counting the longest run

Let see what you have asked for

> I'm supposed to have the function accept 2 parameters: a string or list,

or, generalizing just a bit, a *sequence*

> and a character

again, we'd speak, generically, of an *item*

> to search for. The function should return, as the value of the
>     function, an integer which is the longest sequence of that character
>     in that string.

My implementation of the function you are asking for, complete of doc
string, is

```
def longest_run(i, s):                                                      
    'Counts the longest run of item "i" in sequence "s".'
    c, m = 0, 0
    for el in s:
        if el==i:
            c += 1
        elif c:
            m = m if m >= c else c
            c = 0
    return m
```

We initialize `c` (**c**urrent run) and `m` (**m**aximum run so far) to zero,
then we loop, looking at every **el**ement `el` of the argument **s**equence `s`.

The logic is straightforward but for `elif c:` whose block is executed at the end of a run (because `c` is greater than zero and logically `True`) but not when the previous item (not the current one) was not equal to `i`. The savings are small but are savings...

---

#### Flipping coins (and more...)

How can we simulate flipping *n* coins?  We abstract the problem and recognize that flipping *n* coins corresponds to choosing from a collection of possible outcomes (for a coin, either *head* or *tail*) for *n* times.

As it happens, the `random` module of the standard library has the *exact* answer to this problem

> ```
> In [52]: random.choices?
> Signature: choices(population, weights=None, *, cum_weights=None, k=1)
> Docstring:
> Return a k sized list of population elements chosen with replacement.
>
> If the relative weights or cumulative weights are not specified,
> the selections are made with equal probability.
> File:      ~/lib/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/random.py
> Type:      method
> ```

Our implementation, aimed at hiding details, could be

```
def roll(n, l):       
    '''Rolls "n" times a dice/coin whose face values are listed in "l".

    E.g., roll(2, range(1,21)) -> [12, 4] simulates rolling 2 icosahedron dices.
'''              
    from random import choices
    return choices(l, k=n)
```

---

#### Putting this together

```
def longest_run(i, s):                                                      
    'Counts the longest run of item "i" in sequence "s".'
    c, m = 0, 0
    for el in s:
        if el==i:
            c += 1
        elif c:
            m = m if m >= c else c
            c = 0
    return m
def roll(n, l):       
    '''Rolls "n" times a dice/coin whose face values are listed in "l".

    E.g., roll(2, range(1,21)) -> [12, 4] simulates rolling 2 icosahedron dices.
'''              
    from random import choices
    return choices(l, k=n)

N = 100 # n. of flipped coins
h_or_t = ['h', 't']
random_seq_of_h_or_t = flip(N, h_or_t)
max_h = longest_run('h', random_seq_of_h_or_t)
max_t = longest_run('t', random_seq_of_h_or_t)
```